# Custom Return Type on Custom CrudRepository Method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to write an interface that extends CrudRepository that will return a list of a particular field. When I use that method, I get ConverterNotFoundException. I have two questions:

1. Is there a specific Spring Boot query if I want a list containing a specific field?
2. Am I implementing the converter correctly? I am not sure how to call WebConfig.

```
// EmployeeRepository.java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    List<String> findByEmployeeId(String employeeId);   // ConverterNotFoundException. Expecting list of employee's full name
}


// EmployeeToStringConverter.java
@Component
public class EmployeeToStringConverter implements Converter<Employee, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Employee source) {
        return source.getFullName();
    }
}


// WebConfig.java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new EmployeeToStringConverter());
    }
}


// Employee.java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="FullName")
    private String fullName;
    @Column(name="NickName")
    private String nickName;

    public HubKey(String fullName, String nickName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }
}


// Exception when calling EmployeeRepository.findByEmployeeId()
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.jon.demo.domain.entity.Employee] to type [java.lang.String]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter you have registered in the WebMvcConfigurer is used for formatting data in the view(The view in MVC).

You should add converter to Spring Data related custom conversions beans, every Spring Data sub project has its own registration entry there.

Please read the Spring Data related docs.